# 18.04 Kubuntu: Bluetooth 5.0 earbuds problem - they would pair but not connect

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I'm trying to connect my new [Bluetooth 5.0 (Truengine SE by soundpeats) airbuds](https://www.soundpeatsaudio.com/en/true-wireless-earbuds-truenginese.html#product.info.specifications) but they won't connect. My journaltcl is outputting this error:

```
Apr 02 16:37:31 darkness bluetoothd[1125]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 00:14:BE:70:5C:86: Device or resource busy
```

I tried updating bluez to the latest version available, tried configuring the whole thing via command line, installed the pulseaudio-module-Bluetooth package, but there's no way for those tiny fuckers to connect. They work like a charm both on my phone and on a Windows PC. Can't even say that is my Bluetooth driver faulty because it works if I connect it with my phone.
The Bluetooth CLI utility says they do connect, but after a very short while they disconnect, and they loop this thing endlessly. They don't work at all though, can't hear any audio from them besides the usual "buzz" in the very short time they stay connected.

I am running Kubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && lsusb -v : https://pastebin.com/dFgfVnQT

Comment: Please run _sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && lsusb -v_ then highlight and copy the resulting text. return here, click [edit] and paste that text into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]